# Clipping 5 km area of watershed upstream from outlet using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, clip, upstream

I am using ArcMap.

I have the delineated watersheds for more than 200 sites. What I need is to clip the 5-km area upstream of the sites. https://i.stack.imgur.com/S19Me.jpg.

I cannot do this manually for all sites and I am looking for any ideas that can be helpful to cope with the issue.  It would be doable even with rasters, knowing the size of raster pixels.

Is there any tool to select like 2000 pixels upstream a specific point?

It cannot be like a buffer as the buffer create a circle or square all around the sites not the upstream.

[image]

Comment: Aren't you going to run into a situation where at cell selection 1999 you have the option of selecting one of potentially thousands of cells to get to 2000?

Comment: Convert outlets to no data and compute flow length. Everything below  5000 is your answer.

Comment: Thank you @FelixIP. can you explain it a little more? So I convert the watershed into raster first?

Comment: Make sure your outlets sit on high flow cells. Convert points to raster using any field. Con(isnull(pointrasrer),FlowDirection)). Use output as input to flow length.